# groovy String not executing with .execute() the same way it does on command line

Tags: regex, bash, groovy

I am writing a groovy method to delete new line characters from a file.

```
def removeEmptyLines(filePath){
    cmd="""sed -i '/^\$/d' ${filePath}
    """
    println cmd
    result = cmd.execute()
    result.waitFor()
    println result.exitValue()
}
removeEmptylines("/path/to/file.txt")
```

my output is:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' /path/to/file.txt
1
```

the file remains unedited and obviously the exit status is non-zero. 
however, if i literally copy and paste the first output into command line, it works. I'm using absolute paths.

My guess is that groovy doesn't like the regex characters in my command. how do i get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes (you dont need to quote for the shell, because no shell is involved).

`String.execute()` is usually not what you want, because it splits at whitespace.  So you are better off with either `["sed", "-i", ... ].execute()` or if you need shellisms use `["sh", "-c", "sed -i '..."].execute()`.

Comment: that's a great answer! but how would i run something in the shell from groovy as it is? sometimes i need to use a longer line, for example.